# Free Php encrypter with a key or one way encryption

Tags: php, obfuscation

I have a php project and which I need to deploy in multiple client location and I want to encrypt the code. Is there any free php code encrypter ? I don't want to install any separate libraries.

Basically I want something like [this](http://www.rightscripts.com/phpencode/index.php).

`eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(`

But the problem with this is we can decrypt back this code using [this](http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php).

Is there any encrypter which will use a key (I dont want to place this key in client side) to convert the code so that only I can decrypt the code not by the end user ? Or Is there any one way encryption (which the client could not able to decrypt at all) ? I have searched in this site before posting and I could not find any solution. Plz guide me

Comment: Thats called Obsfucation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182704/how-to-protect-my-php-code

Comment: How will the clients be able to run the php code if they cannot decrypt it?

Comment: Is the "end user" someone with a PHP server executing the PHP code or someone using the website/application that the PHP code provides?

Comment: Ya, I have checked that link already. I tried with POBS and CodeEclipse. POBS is changing only the variable names, function names. It is easy replace all those with giving meaningful names by doing a global search/replace. CodeEclipse is doing page by page encryption. It will not work if I include one file within another and use the variables of first file ( In second file also I can see the same variable). Raizlabs I could not see the file to download.

Comment: @james - End user will be having a copy of the php code.

Answer (score 4):

Any encryption will rely on a php extension to interpret some kind of byte code. I only know about commercial encrypter like SourceGuardian.

Most people suggest to protect code by license agreement with your customer. This is based on some type of trust but should satisfy a lot of problems like what the customer can do with maintanance of the program in case you are unavailable.

Comment: +1 for license suggestion. I asked a question like this once, and the answer was "you can obfuscate, but if people want your code enough, they will find ways around it. The best way is to use a license, or host it server side."

Answer (score 0):

Zend Guard offers irreversible encryption. To my knowledge there is no free product which does the same.

Comment: I'm surprised it hasn't been cracked yet, since by definition that encryption can't be irreversible, like the one of PDF files and former iTunes' .m4p

Comment: Nothing encrypted is irreversible, it is always only a question of investing time and money. The question often is to make it most hard especially for people with no or less knowledge. But in this case license agreements are often preferred. They eliminate to possiblity of the encryption to cause problems. PHP version changes often made problem with encrypters based on my experience.

Comment: That's because it's not encryption but actually compilation (probably mixed with obfuscation and some - crackable - encryption).

Comment: Checking the Zend Guard's product page, it makes much lesser claims than you do - this quote sums it up most succintly: "As a result it protects your code from casual browsing." While still rather impressive (for what is essentially a scripting language), it's a far cry from "irreversible". http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Answer (score 0):

Virtually all PHP "encryptors" can be decrypted easily. They all rely on the same flaw: in order for the script to run, PHP needs to parse the unencrypted source code. And if PHP can get the unencrypted source, so can the user.

There are only few applications (like [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)) that do a proper job of protecting PHP source code.

Answer (score 0):

i think you dont get happy with a free product.. theres no way to do encode code securely whithout a php extension… I would give decoders like Zend Guard or ionCube a try ;)

Comment: But it is difficult for me to install it in every clients machine/ask them to buy the product

Comment: often hoster already support ioncube. also the php extension is free.. so the only one have to pay are you, for the decryptor

Comment: it is an intranet application

Comment: @binoy SourceGuardian (and the other also I think) are free for your client. The decoder component is free. The encoder and license file generator have to be licensed by you. You buy it once - and can supply any number of clients with "encoded" apps. Especially for intranet apps it should be rather easy to install a php extension. Also think again about license agreements and do not forget to mark an answer as accepted - I think everythink is said.